# Stage doesn't show in task

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

Ok, so i have this piece of code here:

```
public class JavaFXApplication1 extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Thread thread1,thread2;
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);
        ForkJoinPool customPool = new ForkJoinPool(4);



        Task<Void> task1 = new Task<Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void call(){
                    int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(null);
                    if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){

                    File file = fc.getSelectedFile();
                    System.out.println(file.getName());
                }
                return null;
            }
        };


        Task<Void> task2 = new Task<Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void call(){
                System.out.println("Task2");

               primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
               primaryStage.setScene(scene);
               primaryStage.show();

                return null;
            }
        };

        customPool.submit(task1);
        customPool.submit(task2);
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

and in task2 i got only a "Task2" communicate. I have tried to find a solution but i have no idea why program doesn't want to go further i mean why it doesn't want to display the stage.

Comment: You can only show a JavaFX stage in the FX Application Thread. You can only show a swing dialog in the AWT event dispatch thread. It is not at all clear what you are trying to do here.

Comment: Well, nothing special. I was just trying to figure out how multithreading works in Java and I was wondering why primaryStage doesn't show. So it doesn't show beacuse it already works in other thread, yeah?

Comment: No, it doesn't show because `primaryStage.show()` throws an exception. Add `task2.setOnFailed(event -> task2.getException().printStackTrace());`.

Comment: Yeah, it throws, Thank you!